# Is using the destructured state to calculate new state with react hooks safe?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is using the destructured state to calculate new state safe?

For example:

```
const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);
//then later
setClickCount(clickCount + 1)
```

I know with classes using this.state + 1 would not be ok and the best would be to use the overload of setState that provides the previous state. Given that the docs use an example similar to what I have above and that there is not mention of this I assumed it is safe. That is until I discovered that the setState action signature is:

```
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
```

If it is safe I am now curious why this optionally can provide the previous state to the function. Otherwise when would you need this when you have destructured the current state that supposedly would be in sync?

### EDIT:

For reference this is what the documentation says about setState with this.state:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState
>   and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how the `setState` API in class components accepted a function as a paremeter, hooks also accept the same.

From the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) : You can always pass a function in case you want to use the fresh state from previous overload.

> does that mean that also like this.state there is no guarantee that the mutation has happened with the destructured state using hooks?

Even though the way state is obtained in classes and hooks is different, the `setState` API itself has similar implementations in both. It is still asynchronous. Hence no matter how you access the state, (`this.state` in class, or `state` in hooks), it is possible that a stale state might be used based on your code. 
Example :

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 2)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}


class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialCount;
  }

  render() {
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => this.setState(count + 1)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState(count + 2)}>+</button>
    </>
  }
}
```

Have implemented same component in two ways. But both of them do not guarantee that previous state value would be used in subsequent `setState` statements. Hence in these cases its best to pass a function in both hooks and classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,the question specifically though is given that this option is there does that mean that mean that also like this.state there is no guarantee that the mutation has happened with the destructured state using hooks?

Comment: Yes. The hooks state also may not be mutated. In above example, right after the first `setCount`, the value of `count` does not get mutated before the second `setCount`. This is due to React batching state updates.

Its exactly same as classes. Just that they have moved to a different API. Implementation is still the same, hence the common pitfalls exist here too.